# Strong law of large number for semimartingale

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, limit-theorems

I just want to know if for semimartingale $X$ we have $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_{t}}{\langle X\rangle_{t}}=0$ or when it is possible. I know it is true for Brownian motion.
Thanks

Comment: Those who voted to close as "unclear": it seems a perfectly clear question to me.  Shouldn't you at least leave a comment saying what is unclear?

Comment: A note: of course you will have to exclude deterministic bounded-variation processes for which $\langle X \rangle_t \equiv 0.$  Likewise, I guess you can see it won't be true for $X_t = B_t + t$.

Comment: if X is a Wiener integral (a stochastic integral with deterministic integrand $\sigma$), your limit will be 0 if $\sigma^2$ is not integrable over $[0,\infty)$, or a non trivial Gaussian random variable otherwise.

Comment: @marcoromito +1, and I think it's worth you posting it an answer-- for $\sigma$ deterministic $X_t := \int_0^t\sigma(s)dB_s$ has Normal distribution with mean zero and variance given by the Ito isometry $[X]_t = \int_0^t\sigma^2(s)ds$.  If $[X]_\infty := \lim_{t\to\infty}[X]_t$ is finite then $X_t/[X]_t \to N(0,1/[X]_\infty)$.

Comment: I guess it is sufficient that the bounded variation part $A$ of $X$ has $A_t/[X]_t \to 0$, and $[X]_t \to \infty$